# If cell string contains word from list in column, return value to new cell

Tags: excel, database, vba, function

First StackOverflow question :)

Within Excel, I have a list of all of my products (some 6000 odd). What I am wanting to do is:

Based on the description of the product (shown in Column C), if this cell contains **ANY** of the listed brands in Column D. Then Column E needs to fill the brand associated with the cell in Column C (Item description).

Please the example as shown

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use following array formula:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$7,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(N(IF(1,(SEARCH($D$2:$D$7,C2))))),0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Legend. Thank you so much! Further to this formula is it possible to - Within Column F, make the description (Column C) contain everything minus the Brand Name (Column E). Based on your example above cell F2 would read - 10" AA.

Comment: Formula in F2 `=SUBSTITUTE(C2,E2,"")`. Also, if this answers your question please [upvote, accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).